# Can Sketch copy moves that was used on the previous Pokémon, and does this differ over generations?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, pokemon-third-generation

In Gen 2, if the enemy Pokémon takes you out with a move, and you send out a Smeargle to Sketch it, i believe Sketch will fail? So Sketch has to be used by the same Pokémon the desired move was used on?

In Gen 3 this doesn't matter? As long as it was the last move used by the opponent? So let's say you're taken out by a Thunderbolt, can you then send out a Smeargle to Sketch it?

What if the opponent is inactive due to sleep or paralysis? Can you still sketch the last move they used before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sketch_(move)):

##### 2nd Generation

> Sketch allows the user to learn the target's last move permanently, replacing Sketch in the process.

So, apparently, Sketch just copies the last move used, it doesn't matter if one of your Pokemon was sent KO or who was the target of that move.

##### 3rd Generation

> Sketch can copy a move a Pokémon attempted to use, but failed to due to sleep.

This means you will learn the last move attempted to use, not the last that was actually completed.

<sub>**Note:** *Remember that Smeargle must be faster than the opponent in order to guarantee a successful Sketch.*</sub>